# Android Facebook API feed dialog?

Tags: android, html, facebook, api

Ok so I have setup a new Facebook app and I have the API and all that jazz setup also and have made successful posts to Facebook using the API. Here is my issue.

How do I format the text the way I want too??

For example:

```
description += "First line \r\n";
description += "Second line \r\n";
```

I am using the Facebook Android SDK and using the Feed Dialog approach as listed **[here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/)**

Also, I am using the feed dialog like so:

```
String description += "First line \r\n";
description += "Second line \r\n";
Facebook facebook = new Facebook("MY_APP_ID");
SetAccessToken(mContext, facebook);
params.putString("link", "");
params.putString("picture", "");
params.putString("name", "");
facebook.dialog(mContext, "feed", params, new Facebook.DialogListener() {

public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {

}

public void onError(DialogError e) {

}

public void onComplete(Bundle values) {

}

public void onCancel() {

}
});
```

Whenever, I do that it pulls up my Facebook dialog and the lines are not separated by line feeds. I also tried to use HTML such as

```
<p>Line 1</p>
<p>Line 2</p>
```

My guess is that I need to use another method in order to actually post formatted text, other than the feed dialog. I know that other Facebook apps are posting to users feeds with properly formatted text. Just not sure why the SDK doesn't offer the same functionality.

**EDIT 1**

Just to add this, the submission is actually in a URL format at the end anyway. I tried adding URL escape characters but that didn't seem to do anything for me.

```
String url = endpoint + "?" + Util.encodeUrl(parameters);
```

Then they pass that into a webview. So I am currently looking into this. Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

as far as I have researched...facebook doesn't allow it's domain image to be posted on wall through post. So, we can't use it. Now what I am doing is getting the imge through following code:

```
ImageView user_picture;
        user_picture = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.user_picture);
        URL img_value = null;
        Bitmap mIcon1 = null;
        try {
            img_value = new URL("http://graph.facebook.com/XXXX/picture");
            try {
                mIcon1 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(img_value
                        .openConnection().getInputStream());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block 
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if(mIcon1!=null){
            user_picture.setImageBitmap(mIcon1);
        }
```

if you want it to convert to byte array

```
 ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();   
        mIcon1.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);    
        b = baos.toByteArray();
```

Sending this image to my server and then posting to wall.

Comment: Mike thanks fr the example but I need help figuring out why this wasn't accepting new lines

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
String message = "<p>Line 1</p><p>Line 2</p>";
params.putString("message", Html.fromHtml(message).toString());
```

Comment: Let me try this tonight when I get home. I remember seeing an example like this but forgot to try it.

Comment: That is a negative. I looked at the Facebook API and I will add this as an edit to my question. It is simply using the URL to send the data in.

Comment: Oddly enough the URLEncoder takes in the \r\n and replaces it with Line+1+%0D%0A+Line+2 so I am not sure as to why Facebook isn't allowing the multiple lines. This is really annoying. I know people using the PHP versions of the Facebook api do not have a problem with this at all. So I guess I need to figure out how to use those instead.